# Role overrides in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I've been going far and wide to see how I can resolve the problem I will outline shortly. I know there are includes and variables and defaults but I just can't grasp the best way to implement the following:

## Defaults

One playbook (site.yml)

```
- hosts: local
  name: Just run it
  roles:
   - role1
   - role2
   - role3
```

that defines 3 roles: role1, role1 and role3 and the files are laid out like

```
- site.yml
  - roles
    - role1
      - tasks
        - main.yml
    - role2
      - tasks
        - main.yml
    - role3
      - tasks
        - main.yml
```

This runs for the most cases as a default scenario (no variable passed)

## Variations

So now imagine I have two other scenarios that slightly deviate from my defaults. The scenario is triggered by passing in a variable say `test_type=1`. In each scenario I still want to run all 3 roles however in scenario 1 I want a different logic in `role1` and in scenario 2 a different code for `role2`

So if I run my scenario #1 I'll get:

```
custom role1, role2, role3
```

And for scenario #2:

```
role1, custom roile2, role3
```

I have ability to output alternative `role1` and `role2` folders to a separate locations but where? What would be the best way to organize something like this?

Generally speaking I want to inherit from my default scenario by only overriding what I need while leaving most of the logic untouched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! It's possible to do what I asked for. Here's one way of doing it:

First of all - do not place default roles into `ansible/roles` location. Rename `roles` into something else, like `default_roles`. This is important, what I describe below will not work because `ansible/roles` seems to be immutable default where Ansible will be looking for roles first.

Place alternative roles in some other location. If you need multiple alternative scenarios you need to create multiple locations. For example you may end up with something like this:

```
- site.yml
  - default_roles
    - role1
      - tasks
        - main.yml
    - role2
      - tasks
        - main.yml
    - role3
      - tasks
        - main.yml
  - test1_roles
    - role2
      - tasks
        - main.yml
  - test2_roles
    - role3
      - tasks
        - main.yml
```

Now when you run the plain command `ansible-playbook site.yml` you will get error `the role 'role1' was not found` but try this: `ANSIBLE_ROLES_PATH=default_roles ansible-playbook site.yml`. You playbook runs. And luckily `ANSIBLE_ROOT_PATH` can have multiple locations. So if you do `ANSIBLE_ROLES_PATH=test1_roles:default_roles ansible-playbook site.yml` you will see that the `role2` will now be picked from the `test1_roles` folder. The key here is to put alternative location before the default one.

The same variable can be set in `ansible.cfg` as `roles_path=foo:bar:zoo` but setting the environment variable seem to be more dynamic and works for my case

Also it's not required to have `test1_roles` folder on the same level as `default_roles`. It can be anywhere and you can use absolute or relative path to point to it. For example `ANSIBLE_ROLES_PATH=../test1/roles:default_roles ansible-playbook site.yml`

IMPORTANT: I wasn't able (so far) to provide `roles_path` other than the way I'm showing here. Providing command line variable or setting variable in the playbook doesn't help because this is configuration variable and it has to apply to the ansible process itself.

If someone has more elegant way of doing this I'll be happy to see it

Comment: The crucial point is to not name your default roles diretory `roles` - anything else is fine, then order the paths in your configuration. There are several ways to configure this, they all should work, I am using my own `ansible.cfg`.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion if your role should behave differently depending on inputs then it should be done at the role level. One way you can do this is by defining a default variable in defaults/main.yml under the role:

test_type: 0

Then, if you don't pass in any variable, it can just use the default value. If you pass in a value, then the role can do additional logic based on what is being passed in.

Comment: Thanks but it's not what I'm looking for. I don't want the same role to behave differently, I want a different role in place of the original based on role name